# I am converting PDF to html using gufy/pdf-to-html package on GitHub . But it showing error that: Undefined array key "pages"

Tags: php, laravel, pdf-to-html

the controller code is below

```
public function generate(Request $req)
    {
        Config::set('pdftohtml.bin', 'C:/poppler-0.37/bin/pdftohtml.exe');
        Config::set('pdfinfo.bin', 'C:/poppler-0.37/bin/pdfinfo.exe');
        $pdf = new Pdf('document.pdf');
        $pdfDom = $pdf->getDom(['ignoreImages' => true]);   
        $html = $pdf->html();
        $total_pages = $pdf->getPages();
        $html->goToPage(1);
        $paragraphs = $html->find('body > p');
```

}

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you please vardump the $html and $total_pages vars ?

Comment: die and dump not working on $html

Comment: can any body help

Comment: what do you mean it is not working, can you please show what is dumped ?

Comment: I searched it but the problem was in poppler. but now its's showing another error:preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 4

Comment: probbaly, goToPage(1) tries to reach pages key in an array. Go to that method, check if it's the case. And and add dump the value inside that method.